# How to display page views on the page using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Google Analytics for data to display on our webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857189/use-google-analytics-for-data-to-display-on-our-webpage)

I am using google analytics to track page views and other metrics. I want to display some of the metrics about particular page on the page itself.

How do i do that?

Its more like a public statcounter for that page i need to display.

My solutions is in ASP.net MVC 3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857189/use-google-analytics-for-data-to-display-on-our-webpage/

Comment: Were the stats for public consumption or for internal use only (i.e. you would need to be in some sort of admin mode to see them).  I have developed a 3rd party service ( http://www.embeddedanalytics.com ).  Right now our service does not have this capability.  But I have thought about such a thing many times.   It would not be difficult to build a java script to pass along the currently viewed page.  But the intent was more from an administrative use and not necessarily for public consumption.  Keep checking back.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the Data Export API. Here is some documentation:

General Dev Info: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/developers-guide

.NET Protocol: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

Comment: I was hoping to find some sample code, as it sounds like its a common request from many others.

Comment: @JewelThief Just got the same idea :) how do you solve this now?